# Error: "Name Prefix" is a required value in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.3

I have made required 'Show Prefix' from admin config setting. Now prefix is shown on the customer account edit page.

But, when i am trying to save customer prefix, then i am getting Error: *"Name Prefix" is a required value."* 
[image]

---

I have also used 'Prefix Dropdown Options' but again, I am getting same error.

[image]
[image]
 I am getting this error in Magento Ver 2.2.1, Ver 2.2.2 and Ver 2.2.3. Is anybody else getting this type error?

Answer (score 0):

**This is a Magento bug.**

Please check this issue at magento  issue list: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7499

Might at this another issue, they have the fix issue

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7241

The fix will be available with the upcoming patch release.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a error, its just validating the form data, if you dont want prefix as a required field, then you can change to OPTIONAL from the magento admin customer configuration settings.

**Steps**: MagentoAdmin->Stores->Configuration->Customer->CustomerConfiguration->Name and Address Options->Show Prefix->Optional

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was a missed value in the table `customer_form_attribute`.

Check if all form codes are maped to prefix attribute:

```
adminhtml_checkout
adminhtml_customer
customer_account_create
customer_account_edit
```

Probably missed `adminhtml_customer` form code is a cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

Go to: Configuration -> Customers tab -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options section -> Show Prefix -> No

Clean the cache, and you will get removal of Name Prefix option from frontend.